# converting a strings to 32-bit binary words using perl

Tags: perl

I have a assembly file generated from a compiler. It declares all the strings as following:

```
LC0:
   .string "Testing...\r\n"

LC1:
   .string "HelloWorld...\r\n"
```

I want to replace these variable-length strings with their corresponding ascii values but in 32-bit wide words like first string should be replaced with 3 consecutive 32-bit wide words i.e. 0x54657374, 0x696e672e, & 0x2e2e0d0a. And then converted in decimal as:

```
LC0:
    .data.32 1415934836
    .data.32 1768843054
    .data.32 774769930
```

and similarly the LC1 to 0x48656c6c, 0x6f576f72, 0x6c642e2e & 0x2e0d0a00 as:

```
LC1:
    .data.32 1214606444
    .data.32 1868001138
    .data.32 1818504750
    .data.32 772606464
```

can anybody help me in doing this.
Regards

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: I m very new to perl. I can extract the string using sed/awk. But could not process the strings in Perl.

Comment: Also, why have you removed the space from "Hello World...\r\n"?

Comment: sorry. it was a mistak. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pack](http://p3rl.org/pack)/[unpack](http://p3rl.org/unpack) are best for this type of conversions. Use [String::Interpolate](http://p3rl.org/String::Interpolate) to safely interpolate backslashed characters (it might not support the same syntax your as your compiler, so test properly).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use String::Interpolate;

my $interpolate = 'String::Interpolate'->new;

while (<>) {
    if (my ($string) = /^\s+\.string\s+"(.*)"/) {
        $string = $interpolate->($string);
        print map "    .data.32 $_\n", unpack 'N*', "$string\0\0\0";
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
LC0:
    .data.32 1415934836
    .data.32 1768843054
    .data.32 774769930

LC1:
    .data.32 1214606444
    .data.32 1868001138
    .data.32 1818504750
    .data.32 772606464
```

Comment: it is giving me error (BEGIN failed--compilation aborted ) at the line String::Interpolate;

Comment: @Sajjad: Have you installed String::Interpolate?

Comment: Fixed a bug in the input used by choroba, and fixed a bug in the answer.

Comment: Is it included in CPAN?

Comment: Yes, that's where I installed it from 2 hours ago.

Comment: @choroba. I have installed the module. if i have a file test.s containing .string type, how can i use your perl script of that file. is it like: script.pl test.s   ???

Comment: I ran this successfully, but it does not replace the first .string "Testing...\r\n" but all the later .string "xxxxxxxx" are replaced successfully. is there something wrong @choroba

Comment: It works for the sample you showed. How are your real data different to the sample?

Comment: I found that the code looks for a space before ". So if there is a tab before ", the above code does not work. How to equally treat a space or a tab before "   ????

Comment: @Sajjad, Use `\s+` instead of a space